# Getting an error after adding solana to my project

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program

I have been getting the following error after adding solana to my project. I have tried adding the @solana/spl-token package ($ yarn add @solana/spl-token) but that didn't work.
Please help.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about development tools that are not specific to solana

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error recently. You haven't posted any code, so I've included an example of what was causing it for me, and how I worked around it.

TLDR;  Set your version to `@solana/spl-token": "^0.2.0".` ...
memo ts build is not compatible, but it looks like it might have been fixed or update in the works at  least: [source](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3479).

OR

Instead of:

```
connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(publicKey, { programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID });
```

This made that error disappear, without needed to change spl-token version:

```
connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(publicKey, { programId: new PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA') });
```

Comment: The error didn't resolve for me after following the above steps.